# How to reset the scroller on ace theme?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a following commented code on the file elements.scroller.js on Ace Theme v1.3.4.

```
$('.ace-scroll').scroller('reset');
```

When the above line is executed on the firebug console, the following error appears.

```
scroller is not a function...
```

Am i missing any javascript file that is not included on the page? that contains the scroller() function.

Comment: Check if the js for scroller is loaded.

Comment: yes all the JS files are getting loaded.

Comment: That code is in your document.ready, is on your main page with HTML or is a single file ?

Comment: Theee are multiple JS files loaded as external files

Comment: Check the order of your JS files, may be you are initializing your scroller before you load your library.

Comment: Thanks Jorge found a way the reset the height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After breaking my head for 2 days found the solution.

```
$('.sidebar[data-sidebar-scroll=true]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if( $this.attr('data-sidebar-hover') == 'true' ) 
        $this.ace_sidebar_hover('reset');
    var sidebar_scroll = $(this).ace_sidebar_scroll('ref');
    var is_element_pos = 'getComputedStyle' in window ?
        function(el, pos) { el.offsetHeight; return window.getComputedStyle(el).position == pos }
        :
        function(el, pos) { el.offsetHeight; return $(el).css('position') == pos }                                  
    var sidebar_fixed = is_element_pos(this, 'fixed')
    sidebar_scroll.set('sidebar_fixed', sidebar_fixed);
    sidebar_scroll._reset();
});
```

The above snippet resets the scroll window height.